# Office JS Add-in API Compose appointment get contact

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I'm searching in documentation how to get the list of contact of the Office account in the way to display it and let the user pick all phone numbers he need.

I assume is not possible during **outlook appointment compose**. But i would to be sure (Maybe i miss an important point in doc)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the feature to get all contacts, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Meanwhile, you can achieve this by using REST API's.